# Reading a file in node.js but when using JSON object, the contents changed

Tags: node.js, json, fs

I'm reading file contents in `nodeJS` as string but when I use content in json object, the content are changed to:

\u0000\\u0000"\u0000S\u0000a\u0000f\u0000e\u0000M\u0000a\u0000t\u0000h\u0000:\u0000 \u0000a\u0000d\u0000d\u0000i\u0000t\u0000i\u0000o\u0000n\u0000 \u0000\r\u0000\n' +

Here is my code

```
let contents = fs.readFileSync('test.txt', 'utf8')

console.log(contents)//working fine
const body = {source:contents}
console.log(body)
```

Comment: How sure are you that the file is *actually* in UTF-8? Can you post a hex dump of the raw data?

Comment: my file is the solidity code, sol file

Comment: That doesn't give me any information I'm afraid.

Comment: I solved the problem

Comment: In that case, you should decide whether you expect it to be useful to anyone else. If so, please edit the question to clarify it, and then add an answer. If you think it won't be useful to anyone else (e.g. because you were reading the wrong file) then delete the question.

Comment: I submit the answer, its in review

Comment: You haven't changed the question though - you should *definitely* do that. Submitting an answer to an unclear question doesn't really help anyone. Editing your question to make the situation really clear and *then* submitting an answer is much more useful.